# How to convert hex string again into cipher text for decryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, hex, pycrypto

I am using [pycrypto](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/crypto/) module for generating a cipher text. The problem is the generated cipher text cannot be saved somewhere since it is not human readable.

```
 >>> a=AES.new("1234567890123456")
    >>> m='aaaabbbbccccdddd'
    >>> a.encrypt(m)
    'H\xe7\n@\xe0\x13\xe0M\xc32\xce\x16@\xb2B\xd0'
```

I want to save this encrypted message in my database, and right now I can't do it since the its not human readable. I can save the data by converting into hexcode:

```
a.encrypto(m).encode('hex')
```

and generate the hex code and save it my database. The problem is how will I convert this `encrypted hex code` back to into same form for decryption? Can anyone help to me here?

My user will access the encrypted message from the database, decrypt it and then check the integrity of the message! Could anyone help me convert hex code back into cipher text?

Answer (score 2):

Do reverse - decode using `hex`:

```
>>> encrypted = 'H\xe7\n@\xe0\x13\xe0M\xc32\xce\x16@\xb2B\xd0'
>>> encoded = encrypted.encode('hex')
>>> decoded = encoded.decode('hex')
>>> encrypted == decoded
True
```

Comment: I used `base64.b64encode(cipher_text)` and `base64.b64decode(instance.encrypted_message)` to decode and encode my data and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolve! :)

You can use `base64.b64encode(cipher_text)` to save your data into database, and then `base64.b64decode(instance.encrypted_message)` to retrieve data. The solution is working for me.

You also need to `import base64`